# Selenium testing tool for .net web application

Tags: testing, automation

I downloaded a selenium testing tool from this  [link](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-dotnet-2.21.0.zip)   but it is not working? I am not getting how to install..

Can anyone suggest the steps for downloading selenium for .NET ?

Comment: http://seleniumtoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/58383

Comment: Swati - i downloaded toolkit from above link, but i want to know that is it a full package including SDK ?

Comment: You need to give more information. What you downloaded is correct, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The best (and easiest way) to install Selenium is via the Nuget package manager in Visual Studio.

Information on using Nuget: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/using-nuget-with-visual-studio-2013/

You can then just search and install 'Selenium Webdriver'. The package manager creates all the relevant package references for you and installs the DLL's in the relevant folder for your project.

You may also want to do the same for Selenium Support as this will give you all extra functionality for Page Objects.